# How to solve syntax error or access violation for PHP Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, laravel

I have two tables which are claim table and claim_type table. Currently, I want to get the name of the claim inside the claim_type table. So, from the table Claim, we will get which type of claim (in the form of id) and after that, we can get the name of the type. I already have queried it inside MySQL workbench like this.

```
SELECT claim_types.name, count(*), sum(amount) FROM myteduh_v1.claims 
join claim_types on claim_type_id = claim_types.id
group by claim_type_id;
```

When I post to the PHP, which to query it is like below. It turns out some error.

```
$ClaimsType = ClaimType::pluck('name')
                ->count()
                ->join('claim_types','claim_type_id','=', 'claim_types.id')
                ->groupBy('claim_type_id')
                ->get();

dd($ClaimsType);

$Claims_pie_chart = Charts::create('pie', 'highcharts')
         ->title('Total Claims Based On Type of Claims')
         ->labels(['$ClaimsType'])
         ->values([15,25,50])
         ->dimensions(1000,500)
         ->responsive(true);
```

After that, I want to insert the `$ClaimsType` into the labels variable to be pie chart labels. The question is, is it wrong the way I query the database inside the PHP controller?

Comment: Clearly, "some error" is not a useful description. Do you expect people to guess? Please paste the exact error message and the line it comes on.

Comment: ClaimType::pluck('name')->count() returns an integer. You cannot use any methods on an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use aggregation in one query, you should use `DB:raw()` in select

```
$ClaimsType = Claim::select(['claim_types.name', DB:raw('count(*)'), DB:raw('sum(amount)')])
                ->join('claim_types','claim_type_id','=', 'claim_types.id')
                ->groupBy('claim_type_id')
                ->get();
```

now you can use `->toSql()` instad of `->get()`, and you will see that query is same as yours raw query.

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.